# Base 64 encoded querystring parameter getting characters replaced

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, query-string

I have a querystring parameter that is an encoded string that gets converted to Base64. That parameter is then embedded in a link within an email. When I click the link in the email, the querystring parameter has had all the + characters within it replaced by space characters. There are no other differences. Is there a method I can call to sanitise the string and effectively replace the spaces with pluses again. I'm currently doing a string replace which is a bit fat hack. Something is causing the replacement but I'm not sure what. Has anyone come across anything like this before?

Example - querystring parameter value within URL of the browser:

`yo3rZZbZyG4UCN+L3pcTYJXmWEggnkW1qcyJk2uBrVTtGUSKIlBcJ8e9TSx8BHjHJv0JhI8H6LbIqUl+3lA7qn+lOgpSi3rCGN4bm5moOWcCA449C1Z3zj7J1FkOXH2HMox4VUZ7x7fF65MRwuBBmw==`

Value of string within controller action:

`yo3rZZbZyG4UCN L3pcTYJXmWEggnkW1qcyJk2uBrVTtGUSKIlBcJ8e9TSx8BHjHJv0JhI8H6LbIqUl 3lA7qn lOgpSi3rCGN4bm5moOWcCA449C1Z3zj7J1FkOXH2HMox4VUZ7x7fF65MRwuBBmw==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should URL encode the base64 string to the link, so it is:

```
yo3rZZbZyG4UCN%2BL3pcTYJXmWEggnkW1qcyJk2uBrVTtGUSKIlBcJ8e9TSx8BHjHJv0JhI8H6LbIqUl%2B3lA7qn%2BlOgpSi3rCGN4bm5moOWcCA449C1Z3zj7J1FkOXH2HMox4VUZ7x7fF65MRwuBBmw%3D%3D
```

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64str)` in .NET, or `encodeURIComponent(base64str)` in javascript

Comment: Spot on - I call `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64str)` on the parameter before embedding it within the URL, works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

you can use System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode (from http://brockallen.com/2014/10/17/base64url-encoding/#comments)

Answer (score 0):

It is doing this because the + sign is interpreted as a marker to say that another parameter follows. This is why it is getting mangled. You should URL encode your string before you pass it to the server.